# Serilog with Asp.Net Core 2.1 not writing from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I am trying to configure `Serilog` to read my settings from the `appsettings.json` file in my ASP.NET Core 2 WebApi.

I have the following in the root of the `appsetting.json` file;

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Async", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel":  "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": { "pathFormat": "Logs\\Serilog\\log.txt" },
              "RollingInterval": "Day"
            },
            {
              "Name": "MSSqlServer",
              "Args": {
                "connectionString": "myconnectionstring",
                "schemaName": "Schema",
                "tableName": "Logs",
                "batchPostingLimit": 1000,
                "period": 30
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In my `Startup.cs` I have the following;

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

If I run the following then the output perfectly so I know its down to the move to appsettings;

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("connectionString", "Logs", schemaName:"Schema")
            .WriteTo.File("Logs\\Serilog\\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
```

And then in my `Program.cs` I have;

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                config.AddJsonFile(
                    x =>
                    {
                        x.Path = "appsettings.json";
                        x.Optional = true;
                        x.ReloadOnChange = true;
                    })
                .AddJsonFile(
                    x =>
                    {
                        x.Path = "appsettings.{currentEnv}.json";
                        x.Optional = true;
                        x.ReloadOnChange = true;
                    })
            )
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

To note, both appsettings.json and the environment specific currently contain the same data.

I have the following versions of Serilog installed;

Serilog 2.7.1
Serilog.spNetCore 2.1.1
Serilog.Enrichers.Environment 2.1.2
Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.1
Serilog.Sinks.Async 1.3.0
Serilog.Sinks.File 4.0.0
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your Program.cs file:

`UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseSerilog()
.Build();`

That will tell the HostBuilder to use the Serilog package.